# Annotate venn diagram in R

Tags: r, venn-diagram

My question involves how to annotate a venn diagram with the actual values in addition to the default counts,
using any R package.
Below is a minimal example of the data:

```
list.items <- list(method1=c("item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"), 
                   method2=c("item1","item7","item3","item4","item8","item6"), 
                   method3=c("item1","item7","item9","item4","item10","item11"))
library(gplots)
venn(list.items)
```

This returns the venn diagram:
[image]
I would like to see for example what the 3 items that method3 has actually are? e.g. item3,item5 & item7.

I would like to have a venn diagram such as the one in:
http://openi.nlm.nih.gov/detailedresult.php?img=3026361_1471-2105-11-S6-S14-9&req=4 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It appears from the documentation not possible to do what you want with `gtools` and `gplots`.  It may be possible using the `vennDiagram` package or `Vennerable` from [enter link description here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=474) R-Forge.

But here is one way to display the elements using the `venneuler` package.

```
library("venneuler")
df <- data.frame(method1=c("item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"),
                 method2=c("item1","item7","item3","item4","item8","item6"),
                 method3=c("item1","item7","item9","item4","item10","item11"))
vd <- venneuler(df)
plot(vd)
```

[image]

Comment: Three circles are expected for the three methods (not items) and the items inside the three circles.